# Remove Unwanted Space

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I am trying to hide unwanted `TextView` and `EditText` fields dynamically using my program. The code is working, but the hidden fields is being replaced with blank space. I wish the other contents below the hidden fields must be automatically get loaded on the hidden field(so that unnecessary scrolls and plain white field can be avoided)

**EDIT 1**
Please find the sample

```
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnXrV.png
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQFm.png
     text3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     edit3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put visibility of TextView and EditText to `View.GONE` not to `View.INVISIBLE`

```
TextView tv;
EditText et;

tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Use as above when you want to hide the view.

Answer (score 1):

this will hide your textview and edittext

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findviewbyId(R.id.textview1);
 EditText et = (EditText)findviewbyId(R.id.edittext1);


 tv.setVisibility(View.Gone);
 et.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```